# find match index group in python

Tags: python, matching, chaining, forward

What the simplest wayto determine which index group is searched in python

example:

desire value

```
Yes, Yes, No
```

value provided

```
A = No, No, No
B = Yes, No, No
C = Yes, Yes, No
```

We want to know which index group matches A, B, or C?

Comment: Can you give more example of input and output? This is very unclear to me.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Suppose we input an array variable with value `[Yes, No, Yes]`.
From the known values of `A [], B [], and C []`, we want to know which group array is same with the input value. the output should be `C`

Comment: How is `[Yes, No, Yes]` the same as `[Yes, Yes, No]`? Is it becaue order doesn't matter?

Comment: @abarnert Yes, i forget that. That must in same order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild leap into the dark here and guess what you're trying to do. If I've guessed wrong, this answer will be useless, and I'll delete it.

Your example is that if `input` is `[Yes, No, Yes]`, it should match `C`, which is `Yes, Yes, No`. So presumably you want to know if `input` has the same elements—in any order—as any of `A`, `B`, and `C`.

One way to do this is by using `collections.Counter` as a multiset:

```
from collections import Counter

A = Counter(('No', 'No', 'No'))
B = Counter(('Yes', 'No', 'No'))
C = Counter(('Yes', 'Yes', 'No'))

input = ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes']
input_multiset = Counter(input)

if input == A:
    print('A')
elif input == B:
    print('B')
elif input == C:
    print('C')
else:
    print('no match')
```

Now, there are ways you could simplify and/or optimize this, but the best way is to rethink the problem. The difference between `A`, `B`, and `C` is just how many `Yes` values each has. So:

```
from collections import Counter

abc = {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C']

input = ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes']
input_counts = Counter(input)
yes_count = input_counts['Yes']
print(abc.get(yes_count, 'no match'))
```

Comment: I think your first answer is I am looking for @abarnert .
I am new in this, and just know there are way like that beside general array. Thank you very much